# Insert image into 8371 document

Tags: libreoffice, templates

I can not insert an image into a 8371 template in .odt format.

I have tried inserting png and bmps.

All it does is show Image 1.

I even tried editing an older business card template but it will not show the image.

I never had this problem when I created the original document.

How can I get Office Writer to show the image in my business cards?

Comment: Does the same happen when you try to insert the same image into different documents? Do the images show up when printing the document?

Comment: Yes, the same thing happens with a new document. It does print correctly.@tohuwawohu

Comment: Are images disabled in LO Writer View settings? Please check the settings in Menu Options -> Tools -> LibreOffice Writer -> View -> Display -> Graphics and Objects,

Comment: Thanks. Images and Charts were unchecked for some reason.